# database schema design for event organizer

Tags: database-design

I have recently embarked myself to learn a project which was given to me by my former co-worker where they gave me a technical challenge to design an golang app, I am still learning the language and also I am trying to comeup with a sane database design. here are the application Goals,

```
Goals 
1. Allow self-registration of users into the system, each user having a unique username and a password. 
 
2. Allow events to be created, scheduled, deleted and automatically archived once the is past. Events should have: 
    1. Owners, the only ones allowed to change event time, description, venue or modify anything but scheduled content for the event. 
    2. Scheduled dates and durations (eg. “starts 2019/04/03 at 10am and ends on 2019/04/04 at 5pm”). 
    3. Venues: An address field where the event will occur 
    4. Description: What the event is about. This can optionally include a picture - an event logo or banner or other descriptive graphic. 

3. Allow existing events to have ad-hoc sessions proposed by anyone who has signed up event. A session should have a title, a basic description, a speaker (by default, the 
user proposing the event) and a duration. 


4 Sessions should be scheduled into the available time for the event in a first-come, first scheduled basis. 
No session can overlap another session. 
If all available time slots have been claimed for the event, no additional 
sessions should be schedulable unless the event owner or a 
session owner deletes or changes the necessary time for a session to make room.
```

I aim to learn a great deal with development of this application, I have created a database schema which made sense to me, help me to improve this application and also develop my thought process.

I intend to use golang, gorm and mux for database abstraction and API development.[image]

Comment: What question specifically do you have about this?

Comment: my can you please sanity of my database design(attached screenshot) and if  my design in not good, can you help me to create a better design given the goals I have.

Comment: One user can only have one session?!